# Completed FB Ads still receiving clicks?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

I had some product carousel facebook ads running over the holidays. The links in these ads were tagged with GA Campaign tracking tags and I am still seeing sessions loading that are coming from these specific links.

Does anyone have any insight into that?

Comment: I would assume they've been cached somewhere or perhaps the links were tweeted or otherwise shared via social media and, hence, are still receiving clicks, possibly by robots.